# Atualizar valores de objetos via GET sem repetição

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

To trabalhando em uma tabela de planos, que possuí um script com vários objetos, dessa forma:

```
var plano_basicoUS = { 
    1: null, // mensal
    2: null, // trimestral
    3: null, // semestral
    4: null, // anual
};

var plano_economicoUS = { 
    1: null, // mensal
    2: null, // trimestral
    3: null, // semestral
    4: null, // anual
};
```

Eu atualizo os valores de cada um via `$.get`, assim:

```
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=monthly", function(resultado){
    plano_basicoUS[1] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=quarterly", function(resultado){
    plano_basicoUS[2] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=semiannually", function(resultado){
    plano_basicoUS[3] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=annually", function(resultado){
    plano_basicoUS[4] = parseFloat(resultado);
});

$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=monthly", function(resultado){
    plano_economicoUS[1] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=quarterly", function(resultado){
    plano_economicoUS[2] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=semiannually", function(resultado){
    plano_economicoUS[3] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=annually", function(resultado){
    plano_economicoUS[4] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
```

Cada consulta do `$.get` retorna um valor como: **10.00**, através do arquivo PHP.

Como são vários objetos, gostaria de não ter que repetir os gets para cada um.

Como posso fazer isso de forma dinâmica, observando que cada `$.get` tem uma URL diferente? Ou então de forma sequencial, se for o caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um objeto array onde você possa pegar o nome do objeto e o `id` que varia de um pra outro:

```
var valores = [
   {plano: "plano_basicoUS", id: 3},
   {plano: "plano_economicoUS", id: 4}
];
```

Em seguida crie uma função para dar loop até o limite de números de itens na array, fazendo um sublooping 4 vezes (quantidade de valores dos objetos) chamando a mesma função sempre que um `$.get` for completado.

Você nem precisa criar os objetos `plano_basicoUS` e `plano_economicoUS` de forma manual, a função já cria eles de forma dinâmica:

O código ficaria assim:

```
var valores = [
   {plano: "plano_basicoUS", id: 3},
   {plano: "plano_economicoUS", id: 4}
];

var contagets = 0;
var contavalores = 1;
function carregaObjs(){
   if(contavalores <= valores.length*4 && contagets < valores.length){

      if(contavalores == 1){
         var periodo = "monthly";
      }else if(contavalores == 2){
         var periodo = "quarterly";
      }else if(contavalores == 3){
         var periodo = "semiannually";
      }else if(contavalores == 4){
         var periodo = "annually";
      }

      var urL = 'buscar_valor.php?id='+valores[contagets].id+'&periodicidade='+periodo;

      $.get(urL, function(resultado){

         //cria os objetos de forma automática
         if(!window[valores[contagets].plano]){
            window[valores[contagets].plano] = {};
         }

         window[valores[contagets].plano][contavalores] = parseFloat(resultado);

         if(contavalores == 4){
            contavalores = 1;
            contagets++;
         }else{
            contavalores++;
         }

         carregaObjs();
      }); 
   }
}

carregaObjs();
```

Comment: Muito bom heim, só não consegui fazer carregar eles, igual aquela função chama() que tu tinha me passado.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração que cria os objetos de forma automática.

Comment: Na questão da função `chama`, vc nem precisa colocar um valor, já pega automático: `function chama(){
   if(contagets == valores.length-1){
      $("select.periodicidades").trigger('change');
   }
}`

Comment: E vc chama a função `chama();` dentro do $.get antes desse if: `if(contavalores == 4){`.

Comment: Funcionou, mas carregou somente os valores do primeiro plano.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no código-fonte: http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/teste.php

Comment: Ah sim, eu tinha colocado no local errado o `chama();`. Como seria para ele carregar os valores junto com o carregando da página?

Comment: Na resposta tem. É só chamar a função `carregaObjs();`

Comment: Algo assim? `$(document).ready(function () {
 carregaObjs();
});`

Comment: Nesse caso não seria necessário a função chama() né? pois ele irá carregar a função inteira.

Comment: Ao adicionar mais itens precisa atualizar algum valor? Pois coloquei 5 select, e não funcionou. Atualizei tbm os valores em: `var valores` e dos objetos iniciais.

Comment: Não, é tudo automático. Vc só precisa adicionar na array `valores`.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78849/discussion-between-dvd-and-wendler).

Comment: Me tira mais uma dúvida?

Comment: pode me ajudar a atualizar o script para exibir o valor da moeda com pontuação nas milhar?

Answer (score 1):

Usa arrays para poderes iterar facilmente e poderes simplificar o código. Em casos destes é bom encontrar padrões para simplificar.

Um exemplo seria:

```js
const periodicidade = ['mensal', 'trimestral', 'semestral', 'anual'];

const promisesPlanoBasico = periodicidade.reduce((promises, periodo) => {
  const nextPromise = $.get(`buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=${periodo}`);
  return promises.concat(nextPromise);
}, []);

const promisesPlanoEconomico = periodicidade.reduce((promises, periodo) => {
  const nextPromise = $.get(`buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=${periodo}`);
  return promises.concat(nextPromise);
}, []);

Promise.all([
    Promise.all(promisesPlanoBasico), Promise.all(promisesPlanoEconomico)
  ])
  .then(([plano_basicoUS, plano_economicoUS]) => {
    plano_basicoUS = plano_basicoUS.map(str => parseFloat(nr));
    plano_economicoUS = plano_economicoUS.map(str => parseFloat(nr));

    // aqui podes usar os valores que foste buscar
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Podes comprimir/optimizar o código ainda mais, se fôr necessário. Podia ficar assim por exemplo:

```js
const promises = ['mensal', 'trimestral', 'semestral', 'anual'].reduce((promises, periodo) => {
  promises[0].push($.get(`buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=${periodo}`));
  promises[1].push($.get(`buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=${periodo}`));
  return promises;
}, [[], []]);

Promise.all(promises.map(Promise.all))
    .then(([plano_basicoUS, plano_economicoUS]) => {
      plano_basicoUS = plano_basicoUS.map(str => parseFloat(nr));
      plano_economicoUS = plano_economicoUS.map(str => parseFloat(nr));

      // aqui podes usar os valores que foste buscar
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```